# CodeIgniter AJAX bug returning same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter

when i try to make AJAX request with jQuery as a response i get the html of the same page ! 
here is a live preview  (edit not available due to me fixing it )

here are my files 
Edit : I have made changes to some of the files

main controller :

```
Class Main extends Controller {

function Main() 
{
      parent::Controller();   
}

function index(){

    $this->load->view('oxila_index');
}}
```

Oxila_index view ( just the JS rest of the html is in the link above )

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#inv").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(evt){

                $.post("/ajax/process", {
                    url: $("#url").val()
                }, function(response){
                        $("#output").html("");
                    $("#inv").show("slow"); 
                        $("#output").html(response);
                }, "text");
                evt.preventDefault();
            }); 
        });
    </script>
```

Ajax Controller

```
Class Ajax extends Controller {

    function process(){

        $data['url'] = $this->input->post('url');
        $this->load->view('test',$data);
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add more code? The output doesn't make sense. echo $this->input->post('lurl'); You have a $this->load->view() somewhere...

Comment: so, what does the view, test.php contain?

Comment: whoops , forgot that , but it contains simple <?php echo $url; ?>

Comment: Hey man, I'm with the same problem (but I'm not using codeIgniter), how did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a person in the forums told me

> you definitely have something in place. Every single path I type in
>   after the url leads me to the home
>   page.
>
> Try changing your URL Protocol from
>   AUTO to something else. (this can be
>   found in the config/config.php file)

i changed it to “REQUEST_URI” and it works !

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your page, and it work well. FYI, I use google chrome in Linux.

I have a few notes though. First, move the `script` from `<head>` to the bottom of the page, above `</body>`. This is best practice, since loading js code will block concurrent loading of other page element, css and images.

Second, if you not change anything in the server side, use `GET` instead of `POST`. To avoid caching in IE, just add another parameter that have random value.

Third, the line `$("#output").html("");` is not necessary. You can put the `$("#output").html(response);` because `.html()` will replace any existing content inside the container. No need to emptied it.

Comment: yes i fixed it last night ill add the solution in a bit , and thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a view for Your Test Function and Your Model to handle the Post Request isnt present

Answer (score 0):

make sure your config has this setting to FALSE;

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why public function?

```
public function test(){

    echo $this->input->post('lurl');

    }
```

Remove public and just make it a function as anyone else: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Try also to include the whole URL in the javascript to try if it work:

```
$.post("http://yourwebsite/oxila/test/")
```